# how to keep gtk.window always on top level

Tags: gtk, vala

I am trying to keep a gtk.window on top, but I'm having trouble.

Here is my code so far. The example is in vala gnome (on windows 7).

```
public void onTop() {
    window.decorated = false;
    window.modal = true;
    window.set_keep_above(true);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is a very old GTK+ bug which was [recently fixed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171456).

You should be able to work around this by calling set_keep_above when the window has already been mapped, i.e. after show(). Comment 17 (from 2008) in that bug says it doesn't work, but it does on my machine, so YMMV.